# Problem with setting remote SDP by using native WebRTC code

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc, sdp

I have a P2P app with flow like this:

**First peer**  - browser, currently using Chromium 78.0.3904.70, 64bit
**Second peer** - native webrtc code (based on: WebRTC M62 branch), environment: Linux Ubuntu 18.04

On the browser side I'm creating an offer with constraints:

```
const constraints = {
   offerToReceiveVideo: true,
   offerToReceiveAudio: true
}
```

Generated SDP:

```
sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 439044357473030896 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:hbv/\r\na=ice-pwd:+kts4bqldeYdmy89dZp7Wv+B\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 5B:D0:4F:CF:FD:80:3D:A1:58:01:C1:AA:90:E8:1F:FA:38:02:B6:58:8A:F2:3C:E7:80:9F:12:0D:B6:5F:CB:81\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id\r\na=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:hbv/\r\na=ice-pwd:+kts4bqldeYdmy89dZp7Wv+B\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 5B:D0:4F:CF:FD:80:3D:A1:58:01:C1:AA:90:E8:1F:FA:38:02:B6:58:8A:F2:3C:E7:80:9F:12:0D:B6:5F:CB:81\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:1\r\na=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:11 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing\r\na=extmap:8 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07\r\na=extmap:9 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id\r\na=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:98 profile-id=0\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:100 profile-id=2\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:102 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f\r\na=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:122 apt=102\r\na=rtpmap:127 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f\r\na=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:121 apt=127\r\na=rtpmap:125 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:107 apt=125\r\na=rtpmap:108 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:109 apt=108\r\na=rtpmap:124 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:120 apt=124\r\na=rtpmap:123 ulpfec/90000\r\n
```

On the native code side I've peer connection factory:

```
factory_ = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(nullptr,
                                                    threads_.worker.get(),
                                                        threads_.signaling.get(),
                                                            nullptr,
                                                                webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioEncoderFactory(),
                                                                    webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioDecoderFactory(),
                                                                        new cricket::InternalEncoderFactory(),
                                                                            new cricket::InternalDecoderFactory());
```

The problem appers when it comes to setting the remote SDP.
Some WebRTC logs:

```
[000:788] [23544] (channel.cc:2105): Setting remote video description
[000:788] [23544] (webrtcvideoengine.cc:609): SetSendParameters: {codecs: [VideoCodec[108:H264]], extensions: [{uri: urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset, id: 14}, {uri: http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time, id: 2}, {uri: urn:3gpp:video-orientation, id: 13}, {uri: http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01, id: 3}, {uri: http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay, id: 12}, {uri: http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type, id: 11}, {uri: http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing, id: 7}, {uri: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07, id: 8}, {uri: http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space, id: 9}, {uri: urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid, id: 4}, {uri: urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id, id: 5}, {uri: urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id, id: 6}], max_bandwidth_bps: -1, }
[000:788] [23544] (webrtcvideoengine.cc:446): Internally supported codecs: {VideoCodec[0:VP8], VideoCodec[0:red], VideoCodec[0:ulpfec]}
[000:788] [23544] (webrtcvideoengine.cc:456): Codecs supported by the external encoder factory: {VideoCodec[0:VP8], VideoCodec[0:red], VideoCodec[0:ulpfec]}
[000:788] [23544] (webrtcvideoengine.cc:553): No video codecs supported.
[000:788] [23543] (channel.cc:853): Failure in SetRemoteContent with action 0
[000:788] [23543] (webrtcsession.cc:345): Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send parameters..
```

Any ideas where can be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have compiled your native WebRTC library without H264 support,
and browser has H264 in the SDP, so it is being chosen as video codec, but your native WebRTC doesn't support it.

Comment: And do you know how to enable h264 support ? It seems like it is off by default. Maybe some gn params or something else ?

Comment: Yes there is a root ninja build file with build switches, set it there.